# Motorola MC55A0 upgrade device window phone 6.5 to 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have a Motorola MC55A0 Mobile device. It's running Windows mobile 6.5 and I'm trying to find a way to update it to Windows Phone 7.5.  I've look around and the usual answer is that upgrades come from the carrier but since it's not used as a phone that's not an option for me. I've contacted Motorola to no avail and I've been looking around for a download of 7.5. Can anyone help me find a way to upgrade this device?

Comment: MC55 isn't a consumer device. The fact that WP7 & 8 are so closed is the reason PDT vendors stay with WM 6.5 or migrate to Android. The use case for PDTs barcode scanning isn't supported. If this is your personal device, just move on and get an actual consumer phone.

Comment: Clearly out of scope for a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. This does not work like your standard PC. You can't just install WP 7 on any phone.